# Neo4j REST queries logged on neo4j server

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

How can I log queries that are run by via the REST API on the neo4j server?
I tried enabling the http logs on the server but the http log file in blank when I run a query using Neo4jClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable http-logging:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html#_http_logging_configuration

This was only fixed in a recent version (so please try 2.1.2)