# How to log query statement to Neo4j server, is it possible?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to log the entire query statement to the Neo4j server, however, after searching SO & the docs I have been unsuccessful. I found this SO question, [Rest Queries Logged on Neo4j Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143880/neo4j-rest-queries-logged-on-neo4j-server), but changing these configuration settings has not achieved what I had hoped. I am working in Golang & using the [Go-CQ](https://github.com/go-cq/cq/) library to communicate with the REST API in Neo4j version 2.1.5.

What I am looking for is the actual query that is being executed, ideally with the parameters being passed as well. Is it possible to log this information? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is about http logging which also includes queries + params + results.
It is not intended for production settings just debugging and testing.

This should work from 2.1.6, see: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/3399

This is currently enabled by setting:

```
 org.neo4j.server.http.unsafe.content_log.enabled=true
```

besides setting:

```
 org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=true
```

In `conf/neo4j-server.properties`, and by augmenting the pattern (`conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml`) to output full requests and responses:

```
 <pattern>%fullRequest\n\n%fullResponse</pattern>
```

Full section in `conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>data/log/http.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>data/log/http.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <!-- Note the deliberate misspelling of "referer" in accordance with RFC1616 -->
      <pattern>%h %l %user [%t{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z}] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}" \nRequest:\n%fullRequest\nResponse:\n%fullResponse</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</configuration>
```

Which will result in an `data/log/http.log` file, with content like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2015:11:23:50 +0100] "POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1" 200 372 "http://localhost:7474/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36" 
Request:
POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://localhost:7474
X-stream: true
Cookie: SQLiteManager_currentLangue=4; __jrDevToolbarSessionId=0x1.b6e143f2c334p-3; JSESSIONID=1AFCE7DCF2D5D7134E933871EBF88252; OSESSIONID=OS1412075842834-2614241454738785158; connect.sid=s%3AkRY6%2B4RyW%2FC2ZUMjfIVqtRRo.shdI5G0zTKSq%2BzKevgXzLEdHnwjUDYP1JFlOhupRf2I; _ga=GA1.1.149316633.1397859613; _mkto_trk=id:773-GON-065&token:_mch-localhost-1384123755719-53900; undefined=0; __atuvc=0%7C47%2C0%7C48%2C1%7C49%2C5%7C50%2C13%7C51
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:7474/browser/
Host: localhost:7474
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Content-Length: 115
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{"statements":[{"statement":"match (n) return count(*)","resultDataContents":["row","graph"],"includeStats":true}]}
Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json

{"results":[{"columns":["count(*)"],"data":[{"row":[0],"graph":{"nodes":[],"relationships":[]}}],"stats":{"contains_updates":false,"nodes_created":0,"nodes_deleted":0,"properties_set":0,"relationships_created":0,"relationship_deleted":0,"labels_added":0,"labels_removed":0,"indexes_added":0,"indexes_removed":0,"constraints_added":0,"constraints_removed":0}}],"errors":[]}
```