# How to log query statement to Neo4j server version 3

Tags: neo4j

I am using `neo4j 3.1` and I want to log all http queries. I've found how it works on `neo4j 2` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764578/6376592).
But I can't configure `neo4j 3.1` the same way, I only see not interesting output like:

```
2016-05-24 12:57:44.940+0000 INFO  [REQUEST] [AsyncLog @ 2016-05-24 12:57:44.939+0000]  127.0.0.1 - null [Tue May 24 15:57:44 MSK 2016] "/db/data/propertykeys?null" 200 -1 "http://localhost:7474/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36" 1
```

Can anyone help me to find way to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

You can activate query logging with the following :

```
dbms.logs.query.enabled=true
```

You can also log query parameters with :

```
dbms.logs.query.parameter_logging_enabled=true
```

The logging will be found in the `conf/query.log` file

Configuration reference :

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#configuration-settings

Comment: From configuration reference I see, that I can log queries that took longer than the configured threshold and only for Enterprise Edition. Can I log just all queries in community edition?

Comment: Good question, I never used community, but if it's written I would say you yes