# Neo4j REST API Logging

Tags: neo4j

I want to activate HTTP logging in Neo4j v3.0.4 including the full request and full the response in the log file. I am using a Windows 10 x64 System and Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.4. 
I found the following information:

[Neo4j Documentation v2.3.3](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_http_logging_configuration)

Also I found several old questions here at stackoverflow, e. g.:

[How to log query statement to Neo4j server, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695517/how-to-log-query-statement-to-neo4j-server-is-it-possible)

My problem is, that I cannot find the neo4j-server.properties file in the current version. I think, this file could be renamed in the current version with neo4j.conf because the contents are very similar.

What I did so far:
changed this parameter in neo4j.conf (directory: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition):

```
    dbms.logs.http.enabled=true
```

added these parameters in neo4j.conf:

```
    org.neo4j.server.http.unsafe.content_log.enabled=true
    org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

created a new file called neo4j-http-logging.xml in the same directory:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>data/log/http.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>data/log/http.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <!-- Note the deliberate misspelling of "referer" in accordance with RFC1616 -->
      <pattern>%h %l %user [%t{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z}] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}" \n Request:\n %fullRequest \n Response: \n %fullResponse </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately I don't get the full request/response. What exactly I have to do in Version 3.0.4 to achieve this?

EDIT:
At the moment an entry in the log looks like this:

```
    2016-09-13 17:25:07.390+0000 INFO  [REQUEST] [AsyncLog @ 2016-09-13  17:25:07.389+0000]  127.0.0.1 - null [Di Sep 13 19:25:07 MESZ 2016] "/db/data/node/1/paths?Accept=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&Content-Type=application/json" 200 876 "null" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36" 10
```

EDIT2:
My Request is:

```
    POST /db/data/node/1/paths?Accept=application/json; charset=UTF-8&amp;Content-Type=application/json HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:7474
    Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6bmVvcGFzcw==
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Postman-Token: 5eae944e-c556-d8f3-cfa1-1bfa92e86761

    {
      "to" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5",
      "cost_property" : "cost",
      "relationships" : {
        "type" : "connected_by",
        "direction" : "out"
      },
      "algorithm" : "dijkstra"
    }
```

and the response is a JSON object with the correct results.

I noticed, that the neo4j-http-logging.xml is not used at all. I can change the configuration but it does not effect the log. There is a flag, that was classified as "experimental" in the Neo4j Documentation v2.3.3:

```
    org.neo4j.server.http.unsafe.content_log.enabled=true
```

that has to be set in the config file to log full requests/response. But according to [Neo4j v3 upgrade](https://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/) this parameter is removed now.
Furthermore I updated to v3.0.6.

Comment: Can you please update your question with what is currently being written to the log file for an http request?

Comment: I updated my post, thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for the edit. What is the query you are issuing to neo4j and are you getting any results?

Comment: Ok, here are my new results. I am not sure if it is even possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)